# Clean up expired certs on a smart card

Tags: windows

How does one remove expired certificates from a Smartcard on Windows?

Answer (score 5):

Great answer in [this blog post][1] by Alejandro Campos Magencio.

> [1]:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/alejacma/archive/2008/10/30/how-to-clean-up-expired-certs-on-your-smart-card.aspx
>
> 1) Run the following command to get a
>   list of certificates stored in the
>   smart card:
>
> certutil -scinfo > output.txt
>
> Note: Certutil tool should be included
>   on Windows Vista/Server 2008 by
>   default. You may also get it from
>   Windows Server 2003 Admin Pack, for
>   instance.   Cerutil may request the
>   smart card PIN several times. You can
>   safely ignore these requests by
>   pressing Esc every time. You will
>   finally get a dialog with a list of
>   certificates in the card (in my
>   particular case I got 3 certs, and one
>   of them had already expired). Now
>   close that dialog and wait until
>   certutil finishes running.   2) Take a
>   look to output.txt. For example, in my
>   case the first cert (“Certificate 0”)
>   was the expired one (I could see
>   strings like “Chain on smart card is
>   invalid”,
>   “CERT_TRUST_IS_NOT_TIME_VALID” and
>   “Expired certificate”). Copy its
>   related “Key Container” value
>   (“f6138188-3725-4c2b-8cf6-9c421d8bee69”
>   in my case).   3) Run the following
>   command to remove the certificate
>   associated to the key container you
>   copied before:
>
> certutil -delkey -csp "Microsoft Base
>   Smart Card Crypto Provider"
>   "f6138188-3725-4c2b-8cf6-9c421d8bee69"
>   Note: your smart card CSP may be
>   different. Use yours.